# How to trigger build for changes in a subdirectory of a Git repo when using CruiseControl.Net?

Tags: git, cruisecontrol.net

I'm in the process of converting from using SVN repos to Git repos for our codebase.  We are attempting to maintain the majority of our existing build/deploy process during this transition, which means building with our existing CruiseControl.NET CI server.

The problem that I'm running into is that we have several different app directories underneath the git root, which is keeping me from detecting a change in a specific subfolder and building only the related application, such as:

```
../gitRepoRoot/appOne
../gitRepoRoot/appTwo
```

Traditionally I've set the svn working directory to something like [../gitRepoRoot/appOne] and just detected the changes off that to build appOne, but so far I can tell there is no way to watch a subdirectory using git.

I'm not a CruiseControl.NET expert by any means, so perhaps I'm missing something or there is another way of achieving the same end?

Comment: Did you find a solution? If the answer below helped please accept it

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have your sourcecontrol block you could use inclusion/exclusion filters to control build triggering.

See: http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Filtered

For example:

```
<sourcecontrol type="filtered">
  <dynamicValues />
  <exclusionFilters />
  <inclusionFilters>
    <pathFilter>
      <pattern>appOne</pattern>
    </pathFilter>
    <pathFilter>
      <pattern>appTwo</pattern>
    </pathFilter>
  </inclusionFilters>
  <sourceControlProvider type="git">
    <autoGetSource>True</autoGetSource>
    <branch>master</branch>
    <commitUntrackedFiles>False</commitUntrackedFiles>
    <dynamicValues />
    <executable>C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git</executable>
    <fetchSubmodules>False</fetchSubmodules>
    <repository>**repo**</repository>
    <tagCommitMessage>CCNet Build {0}</tagCommitMessage>
  </sourceControlProvider>
</sourcecontrol>
```

**Note:**
By default `pathFilter` elements are case-sensitive, but this can be disabled like so:

```
<pathFilter>
  <caseSensitive>False</caseSensitive>
  <pattern>appOne</pattern>
</pathFilter>
```

See http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/PathFilter for other options